# CSS background-image url in .NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, url

Whats is correct way to route to the image in MVC web aplication?
MVC has default routes, e.g. you can reach the same page in several ways:

```
1. localhost
2. localhost/home/index
```

BUT you can and this way, so the root directory changes. So is there any way to set an url from the root.

```
3. localhost/home/index/
```

...

I use MVC 5. Use `*.css` file, which has class with `backgorund-image` set.
The same issue exists if application is  configured on `IIS` as `localhost`, or `localhost/app`.

Example:
Backgroud image:

1. http://88.119.194.40:88/test/Fleet/ro/Auth/Login
2. http://88.119.194.40:88/test/Fleet/ro/Auth/Login/

Comment: Please show your code, and tell us where you get stuck.

Comment: Project/lib/xxx/css folder has image.png and site.css, who's a class .xxx { background-image: url(image.png)}. App is configured as domain/app,  and web looks for domain/lib/xxx/css/image.png but not a domain/app/lib/xxx/css/image.png

Comment: As I mentioned, if you call application : domain/app in fails. if: domain/app/home/index runs ok, if domain/app/home/index/ - fails, and so on..

Comment: There is a solution to write this class in *.cshtml and set a baseUrl which depends on condition if Request.Path.EndsWith('"/"), but I want a clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of MVC you're using.  But, in general, you use root relative addressing (~/).  Content does not change, and is generally placed in a location like ~/Content/images and css in ~/Content/css (or wherever you put them), so therefore your page should always use that.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/site.css">
```

Or similar..

This only works in more recent versions of Razor, however.  In older versions you may need to use the content helper.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Html.Content("~/Content/css/site.css")">
```

EDIT:

I misunderstood the question.  What you're looking for is how to specify the url for an image within the css file.  CSS url's are relative to the location of the .css file, not relative to the location of the page.  So assuming your css folder and images folder are siblings of each other:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../images/backgroundimg.png");
}
```

Since your css file is always in the same location, you never have to change the url to the image.

Comment: @arturas Erik's answer seems correct. Could you care to explain why you down vote?

Comment: I did not downvote, but it is possible they felt you should be using the @Url.Content helper instead, which should obey the routes.LowercaseUrls setting in your route configuration (I believe).  Or possible that they didn't like his answer of Html.Content instead of Url.Content.

Comment: How can you use @Url helpers in *.css file?

Comment: @arturas - It appears I misunderstood the question, and did not realize you were talking about the url in the css itself.  I will update.

Comment: Did you see my update:
Example: Backgroud image:
http://88.119.194.40:88/test/Fleet/ro/Auth/Login
http://88.119.194.40:88/test/Fleet/ro/Auth/Login/

Comment: @arturas - the problem is that you have an inline style element, and not using a CSS file.  Move the selector the site.css and it will work.  When using inline css, the url lookup is based on the page url.  When using a css file, it's based on the css file url.